# Reading XML Attributes into a List

Tags: c#, xml, list, httpwebrequest

I'm new to XML and am having trouble reading my XML response back from a HttpWebResponse.

Here is the response back:

```
<RESPONSE version="1.2">
 <RESULTS>
  <AN an_type="C" 
  an_id="783hdryfdg56a2" 
   an_num="1" 
    an_status="100" />
  <RESULTS>
</RESPONSE>
```

I'm looking to extract out the an_id value and save it to a list. Started doing this but seems to get an for xmlnodelist as an int but it thinks nodes["an_id"] is a string

```
List<int> IDs = new List<int>();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(returnValue);
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("SEARCH_RESULTS/LOAN");
LoanIDs.Add(Convert.ToInt32(nodes["an_id"].InnerText));
```

Also is their a way to once the an_id's are added to a list. foreach item in the list use it as aparameter for a new xml like this:

```
<INPUT>
        <LOGIN API_ID=""cat"" API_PASSWORD=""dog"" />
    <REQUEST>
         <AN an_id=""@anID"" />  
         <AN an_id=""@anID"" />
        ....foreach one in list it adds a new node with the value
    </REQUEST>
</INPUT>
```

Comment: The XPath expression in `SelectNodes` doesn't match the document. It should probably be `RESPONSE/RESULTS/AN`.

Comment: I changed your title radically, since your question has nothing at all to do with WebResponse. If you had taken that XML from a string in memory, you would have had the exact same problem.

Comment: The Xml is from a WebResponse I just didn't show that part of the code. I get the response and save the response (xml) to a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `xml` being your string with the XML code:

```
var ids = XDocument.Parse(xml).
    Descendants("AN").
    Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("an_id")).
    ToList();
```

However, from your sample it didn't seem that the attribute is always an integer. <strike>Are you sure about your conversion?</strike> I changed the cast of the attribute to (string) given your latest comment.

When you want to reuse the list, with `current` being the parent element containing the ones you want to add:

```
current.Add(ids.Select(i => new XElement("AN", new XAttribute("an_id", i))));
```